# Is there simple mechanism to keep a property for a limited period of time in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, memcached

I would like to set property for a X minutes. After that period it should return null or expired.

Is there any simple mechanism in C#?

Like this:

```
  private static TimeCache<LoginData> _session;

  private void Login() {
    ...
    _session.Set(ws.Login());
  }

  private void DoStuff() {
    if (_session.Expired)
      Login()
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Not natively, but it wouldn't be too hard to create.

Comment: Since you are using memcached it does so for you just fine - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967875/memcached-expiration-time... Could you please clarify why that does not work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple class for this.

```
class ExpiringValue<T>
{
    protected T _value;
    protected DateTime _expiration;

    public ExpiringValue(T val, DateTime expiration)
    {
        _value = val;
        _expiration = expiration;
    }

    public T Value => _expiration < DateTime.Now ? default(T) : _value;
}
```

To use it, you could do something this:

```
var message = new ExpiringValue<string>("Hello world", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(10));

Console.WriteLine("The message is set to {0}", message.Value);
```

Comment: Please elaborate @GetoX

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8) event `OnTimedEvent` to reset your property, but be mindful about the thread safety of your property.